# [Why]- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response not invoked

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

When I use unit-test to request web, the connection:didReceiveResponse is not invoked. However, when I use a button in view to request web , this function can be invoked and it works.The code are really the same, just in different files.

Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0):

It is called when enough data has been read to construct an NSURLResponse object.